# Why the Fox H function is different?

Tags: special-functions

Thank you in advance for your time and help. I am new with Fox H function. Allow me to ask some questions.

1. why the definition is different between wiki and mathworld ?  The links are below.  You can see that the + and - sign are different in the gamma functions. 
   wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_H-function
   mathworld: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FoxH-Function.html
2. I do need to understand the meaning of the integration area, is there an example I can see? Thank you.

Comment: Ad 1: Yes there is a sign change, but notice the same sign change in $z^s \rightarrow z^{-s},$ i.e. there is a substitution $s \rightarrow -s$ in the complete integrand.

Comment: oh, thank you sir.  May I ask what's the point or benefit to substitute s to -s ? and also where to see a detail example about the contour integration area for H function?  Thank you again.

Comment: It is a matter of convention. I think that $z^{-s}$ is preferable since it takes the form of an Inverse Mellin Transform. Scaling parameters positive reals is also a matter of convention. If they are negative reals, you can rewrite the Mellin Barnes integrand to make them positive.